# How do I remove the plus sign using regex in postgres?

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have the following two url search strings:

```
?fbad_id=6073971598331

?fbad_id=+6073971598331
```

And I try to decode it with the following,

```
substring("search", '.*[?&]fbad_id=([^$&]*)') as fbad_id
```

But how can I update the code to also remove the plus sign, when it is there?

Comment: There is a flaw in here. `+` after `=` will act as quantifier.

Comment: You are right! I pasted my poor attempt to fix it. =) @Rahul

Comment: So what's your question now ?

Comment: I want it to come out as 6073971598331 for both strings @Rahul

Comment: You can easily search it and replace it with empty string. [Like this](https://regex101.com/r/PjCBog/1/)

Comment: Try `'.*[?&]fbad_id=[+]?([^$&]*)'`. BTW, why use `$` in `[^$&]`?

Comment: Is the `+` always in the same position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a `[+]?` to match 1 or 0 `+` symbols after `=`:

```
select substring('?fbad_id=+6073971598331' from '.*[?&]fbad_id=[+]?([^&]*)');
```

See an [online PostgreSQL demo](http://rextester.com/JQLZKR80474).

**Pattern details**:

- `.*` - any 0+ chars, as many as possible, up to the last occurrence of the subsequent subpatterns
- `[?&]` - a `?` or `&` symbol
- `fbad_id=` - a `fbad_id=` substring
- `[+]?`  - **one or zero `+`** symbols
- `([^&]*)` - Capturing group 1 matching any 0+ chars other than `&` (since `[^...]` is a negated character class)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sorry for being a newbie, I've used Stackoverflow for a while, but I've never posted a question before.